Does it make sense to view religions as Lakatosian Research Programmes?
From Wikipedia:

Research programmes
Lakatos's second major contribution to the philosophy of science was his model of the "research programme", which he formulated in an attempt to resolve the perceived conflict between Popper's falsificationism and the revolutionary structure of science described by Kuhn. Popper's standard of falsificationism was widely taken to imply that a theory should be abandoned as soon as any evidence appears to challenge it, while Kuhn's descriptions of scientific activity were taken to imply that science is most fruitful during periods in which popular, or "normal", theories are supported despite known anomalies. Lakatos's model of the research programme aims to combine Popper's adherence to empirical validity with Kuhn's appreciation for conventional consistency.
A Lakatosian research programme is based on a hard core of theoretical assumptions that cannot be abandoned or altered without abandoning the programme altogether. More modest and specific theories that are formulated in order to explain evidence that threatens the "hard core" are termed auxiliary hypotheses. Auxiliary hypotheses are considered expendable by the adherents of the research programme—they may be altered or abandoned as empirical discoveries require in order to "protect" the "hard core". Whereas Popper was generally read as hostile toward such ad hoc theoretical amendments, Lakatos argued that they can be progressive, i.e. productive, when they enhance the programme's explanatory and/or predictive power, and that they are at least permissible until some better system of theories is devised and the research programme is replaced entirely. The difference between a progressive and a degenerative research programme lies, for Lakatos, in whether the recent changes to its auxiliary hypotheses have achieved this greater explanatory/predictive power or whether they have been made simply out of the necessity of offering some response in the face of new and troublesome evidence. A degenerative research programme indicates that a new and more progressive system of theories should be sought to replace the currently prevailing one, but until such a system of theories can be conceived of and agreed upon, abandonment of the current one would only further weaken our explanatory power and was therefore unacceptable for Lakatos. Lakatos's primary example of a research programme that had been successful in its time and then progressively replaced is that founded by Isaac Newton, with his three laws of motion forming the "hard core".
The Lakatosian research programme deliberately provides a framework within which research can be conducted on the basis of "first principles" (the "hard core"), which are shared by those involved in the research programme and accepted for the purpose of that research without further proof or debate. In this regard, it is similar to Kuhn's notion of a paradigm. Lakatos sought to replace Kuhn's paradigm, guided by an irrational "psychology of discovery", with a research programme no less coherent or consistent, yet guided by Popper's objectively valid logic of discovery.
Lakatos was following Pierre Duhem's idea that one can always protect a cherished theory (or part of one) from hostile evidence by redirecting the criticism toward other theories or parts thereof. (See Confirmation holism and Duhem–Quine thesis). This aspect of falsification had been acknowledged by Popper.
Popper's theory, falsificationism, proposed that scientists put forward theories and that nature "shouts NO" in the form of an inconsistent observation. According to Popper, it is irrational for scientists to maintain their theories in the face of nature's rejection, as Kuhn had described them doing. For Lakatos, however, "It is not that we propose a theory and Nature may shout NO; rather, we propose a maze of theories, and nature may shout INCONSISTENT". The continued adherence to a programme's "hard core", augmented with adaptable auxiliary hypotheses, reflects Lakatos's less strict standard of falsificationism.

Could religions be viewed as Lakatosian research programmes? Rather than viewing religions as theories (as discussed in an earlier question), could we conceptualize them as having a hard core of fundamental assumptions, surrounded by a network of auxiliary hypotheses (such as the various denominations or interpretations within a religion)? If so, how might one modify a religious research programme to enhance its explanatory and/or predictive power, allowing it to be considered progressive rather than degenerative or pseudoscientific (see Imre Lakatos: Pseudoscience)?

NOTE: The inspiration to ask this question came from this answer. A quote from said answer:

Lakatos was talking about science theories, but his Research Programme thinking is very applicable to philosophic worldviews as well. Evaluating the consilience of evidences for or against a worldview, and the overall "life health" of living by a worldview, are how one would apply Lakatos' thinking to worldview competition. Note the "auxiliary assumptions" from Lakatos are the defensive memes of Memeplex theory.
The right way to do an evaluation of competing worldviews is to carefully accumulate the for and against evidences, examine the validity of protective auxiliary assumptions (many protective memes are actually fallacies), and look at the overall utility of the worldviews to live life well. Note that the two commentators agreed that Alex's worldview seemed to be effective and useful in living life, so it scored well on that metric.


Research programs searching for God???

@MauroALLEGRANZA If that's part of the religion's hard core of fundamental tenets, sure.

And what are the "predictions"? Miracles, after life? How to test them?

@MauroALLEGRANZA I suppose it depends on the religion. For instance, the New Age movement seems to make an eclectic mix of diverse predictions.

Lakatosian research programmes were proposed to describe development and decline of scientific theories. As religions do not strive to develop scientific theories, there is no point assimilating them to research programmes either. That is not to say that there are no structural similarities, such as core doctrines and malleable interpretations used to maintain them in the face of changing circumstances. That loose template can be found in multiple social institutions beyond science and religion also, politics and courts of law, for example.

Maybe relevant: RELIGIOUS KNOWLEDGE IN THE LIGHT OF KUHN’S AND LAKATOS’
METHODOLOGICAL CONCEPTIONS (2022)

@MauroALLEGRANZA -- Yes, testing for "miracles" and mystical knowledge, along with life-application success, moral tests, and logical tests are the methods one may collect supporting or refuting data for religions.

@KristianBerry The self-interested choice of enslavement to a cruel and powerful supernatural entity to avoid being tortured by it, Pascal's Wager, is unique to having previously adopted a very specific set of doctrines as true.  As a generalized argument for religion in a plurality of possible options, it fails, as it calls for seeking out the most jealous and vicious of religions, and swearing fealty to it out of fear of the possible worst-case otherwise.  Is the absolutely morally worst religion most likely to be true?

@MauroALLEGRANZA Some religious predictions would be rather difficult to devise tests for, although one could possibly still collect observational evidence.  But there are usually some number of more practical-to-test predictions as well.  Especially the ones that have rules about how one should conduct day-to-day affairs.

@Perkins But religion is not a requisite for successfully conducting day-to-day affairs. We would need to focus on what religion is required for.

@ScottRowe The point was simply that not all of the predictions made by religions are impossible to test.  Testing whether the meek really do inherit the earth, for example, would be reasonably easy to accomplish.

There are a multitude of approaches that are taken to doing philosophy.  That is why, when someone tells you they are "reading philosophy" that tells one almost nothing about the content of what they are reading.  It could be anything from Taoist "flow" treatises, to math theory.
We also have no agreed metric to evaluate utility of different approaches to philosophy.
My approach, of pragmatic empiricism, is a personal choice. It is based on my personal judgement that this is the most useful philosophic stance and school. The circularity this is a "pragmatic" metric of utility, which I then use to justify pragmatism, is not lost on me...
The philosophers who have adopted pragmatic empiricism tend to treat the boundary between science and philosophy as very ill defined, and science as merely a subset within philosophy.  The tools of science, which are refinements of the empirical process, are generally applied by them back into the rest of philosophic problem areas.  This is what I do as well, and is why I generally use the best of scientific thinking on every philosophic problem that is tractable to them.
Worldviews tend to come in families, they tend to have core and ancillary hypotheses, they tend in practice to be adapted over time to deal with contradicting facts, while still maintaining a recognizable familial resemblance.  I at least find postulating a Research-Programme/worldview identicality to be a highly useful conceptual framing.
Religions are a special case of worldviews.  Religions arose as speculative efforts to characterize "what is" and "how we should live", which are key goals of science and philosophy.  However, in contemporary western thought they tend to be primarily identified as a set of dogmas, or claims.  The fixity of this set of dogmas is often asserted by their holders.  Fixity is incompatible with the Research programme methodology, as contrary data is not acknowledged, and ancillary hypotheses never incorporated. Fixity leads to religions being qualified as pseudoscience by Lakatos -- or dismissed as irredeemably degenerated worldviews, if you want to keep them within the evaluation tent.
To treat religions as Lakatosian worldviews, one has to, therefore, expand the frame of what one is evaluating. Despite the claims of fixity, specific religions, and also communities of believers, DO tend to adapt their dogma and practice over a time frame of decades or centuries.  And this adaptation is generally in response to contrary evidences of one sort or another.  The essential Reasearch Programme element of responding to falsifications is actually present when one expands the framing wide enough to discern the sociology of people leaving one denomination and joining another, and of denominations modifying their dogmas.
Returning to my own personal judgement -- despite this moderate degree of adaptability that religious families exhibit, when I evaluate the world's major religions as Research Programmes, I still consider the world's major religions to be terminally regressive, as they still have too many dogmas that have major contradicting evidences that have been known for centuries or millenia.  It is instead the frameworks that the religions fall within, such as Monotheism, Di-theism, Polytheism, pluralist spiritual dualism (shamanism), or atheist spiritual dualism (as in most Buddhism) that I would consider to be a possibly viable candidate to be a progressive programme.
So I at least consider it to make sense, and be useful
BUT-- given the diversity of philosophy -- it is not the case that even all pragmatic empiricists would agree with this. And those who approach philosophy with a very different initial frameworks may not even find this discussion relevant to what they consider essential to philosophy!

I guess the elephant is just too big for any number of people to get their arms around it. It would be great if "how we should live" could be reduced to a fairly short and uniform list that people could keep in mind.

No. Religious belief doesn't aspire to methodological naturalism. As such,  it cannot be a scientific programme. Unlike pseudoscience, religious belief and method have a substantial difference in character that confusing them isn't easy to do in the same way science and pseudoscience might be confused. Christianity, however, adopted natural theology which is an instance of a religion endorsing the methodology of naturalism.

Religious belief isn't pseudoscience in itself, but plenty of people use pseudoscience to try to support religious belief. Christianity uses natural theology, with debatable validity, and only in some part. It still instead relies heavily/primarily on "revealed theology", i.e. scripture and personal experience, while there's also a substantial amount of presuppositionalism, which ideally compares worldviews, but in practice seems to boil down to starting from one's conclusion and reasoning in circles to get back to that conclusion.

@NotThatGuy I think that's good commentary. Reasoning from conclusions to premises is the core of rationalization, and that's also antithetical to good reason.

@NotThatGuy : That's not even unique to religion, many proponents of political ideologies also use pseudoscience to try to support their beliefs. I've even seen plenty of cases of atheists using pseudoscience to try to support their side.

It's a very interesting conception of the situation.
I think Lakatos actually describes a special case of a more general human behaviour, which is that all systems of human reasoning feature some assumptions, whose validity cannot be tested independently, but which are eligible to be adopted because they perform a role in making the system of reasoning internally sound and logically complete in some regard.
Lakatos distinguishes between "auxiliary" hypotheses and "hardcore" assumptions, and the difference is the apparent ease or difficulty with which they may be replaced. Lakatos uses the term "research programme" for a system of reasoning with certain characteristic hardcore assumptions in the context of scientific research.
It seems many or all systems of reasoning contain certain assumptions whose logical connections are so general that the replacement of these assumptions must involve the total revolution of the entire system and resetting of all things within, whereas there are other assumptions whose logical connections are more limited and can be replaced without upsetting so many things.
The effect is that some assumptions may seem to be held only while convenient and are readily dropped too when convenient, whereas other assumptions are stubbornly held, and often appear to gain or lose adherents only on a multi-generational timescale (i.e. assumptions change one funeral at a time).
Ultimately, because the failure of hardcore assumptions must collapse the entire system of reasoning, it is the entire system that is ultimately subjected to the test of whether it is performing its perceived function or not for the holder.
Organised religions then are just another instance of a system of reasoning which may or may not perform a perceived function for an adherent.
If religions are conceived as theories which create some kind of social order and support the practical political management of societies, then its supernatural assumptions may withstand simply because most people perceive that it is working.
Lakatos is so unwelcome amongst many scientists precisely because, by implication, he diagnoses them not as people who are discerning truth or are in possession of a special method, but as people who are fundamentally discerning a correspondence between their theory and their interests (whatever those might be, and may vary between individuals), and that their standards of truth are the same as priests and monks, even if the content of their theories are ultimately different.

Nowadays people do research in all sorts of areas not limited to the exact sciences or even the social sciences, so I would venture the following comparison with Nietzsche's take on a religious leader as an Uebermensch; see for example this question on Nietzsche's Uebermensch on this site.  According to Nietzsche, such a leader/Uebermensch is involved in a task of developing a new approach to structuring life and belief, and as such is a researcher (perhaps in the psychology of religion?) involved in a research program.

Is an ubermensch considered to be divine though?

Not by Nietzsche as far as I know.  Actually it would be good to link some specific studies of Nietzsche's portrayal of specific historical religious leaders.  What I wrote is purely from memory; I haven't looked for references yet.  If you know of any, do let me know.  @ScottRowe
